# Start exe from Windows Service using different credentials

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

I have a WCF service (exe) that I started via a console app using a different credential by passing the Domain, UserName and Password in the ProcessStartInfo() information.  Using the code, the value for 'User name' in Task Manager for the 'exe' is 'TestUser'

```
    var dpmProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Debug",
                    FileName = "",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    Domain = "xx",
                    UserName = "TestUser",
                    Password = password, /*using SecureString*/
                    Verb = "runas"
                }
            };

            dpmProcess.Start();
```

I tried to do the same in a Windows Service Code, but my exe is not started.  I used 'Impersonation' and my exe was started.  However, the 'User name' in the Task Manager is 'SYSTEM' and not the 'UserName' (TestUser) I passed in Impersonation.

```
    //*start impersonator (2)
            using (var imp = new Impersonator(LOGIN, DOMAIN, PASSWORD))
            {
                WriteToFile("Starting..");

                var dpmProcess = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        FileName = "xxx",
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        ErrorDialog = false,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    }
                };

                dpmProcess.Start();

                WriteToFile("Started..");
            }
```

[image]

Is it possible to start exe in Windows Service and see the Username as same as running the exe in Console App?

Thanks!

Comment: Best share the bit of code where you start your `exe`

Comment: @noel updated information

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the the sc create command:

If i understand your needs correctly,
based on this article:

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config)

You can use the sc command to run the service with the permissions of your desired user.

```
sc.exe [<servername>] create [<servicename>] obj= "[.\username]" password= "[password]"

For example:

sc.exe \\10.0.0.0\ create NewService binpath= c:\windows\system32\NewServ.exe obj= ".\Administrator" password= "MySuperSecurePassword@"
```

If that's not what you want to do you can also use schtasks.exe to reach you desired goal:

```
schtasks /create /sc ONCE /tn MyCoolTask /tr <path_to_executable> /ru "domain\user_name"

schtasks /run /tn MyCoolTask
```

Good luck, hope that helps :)

Comment: Updated the initial information.